# Why does the Postgres position() function give different results?

Tags: postgresql

I am baffled at to why the Postgresql position function gives different results for what seems to be a straightforward test.

Here is query #1:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM 
    dnasample D, ibg_studies ST, subjects S
WHERE 
    D.studyindex=ST.studyindex
    AND ST.studyabrv='CONGER'
    AND D.subjectidkey=S.id
    AND D.projectindex IS NULL
    AND POSITION('Previous subjectid:' in D.comment) IS NULL
```

which returns a result of 246.

Then here is query #2:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM 
    dnasample D, ibg_studies ST, subjects S
WHERE 
    D.studyindex=ST.studyindex
    AND ST.studyabrv='CONGER'
    AND D.subjectidkey=S.id
    AND D.projectindex IS NULL
    AND POSITION('Previous subjectid:' in D.comment)=0
```

I do not see why these return such different results?

I've tried reading the Postgres documentation to clarify the difference between zero and the null string, but not much luck there yet...

Thanks in advance, 
--Rick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`position(needle in haystack)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL) function will return:

- Zero if `needle` is not NULL and not in `haystack` and `haystack` is not NULL.
- A positive value if `needle` is in `haystack` with one being the beginning of `haystack`.
- NULL if `needle` or `haystack` are NULL.

For example:

```
=> select position('a'  in 'a' ) as a,
          position('a'  in 'b' ) as b,
          position('a'  in null) as n1,
          position(null in 'a' ) as n2,
          position(null in null) as n3;
 a | b | n1 | n2 | n3 
---+---+----+----+----
 1 | 0 |    |    |
```

That empty spots under `n1` through `n3` are NULLs.

So this condition:

```
POSITION('Previous subjectid:' in D.comment) IS NULL
```

is equivalent to:

```
D.comment IS NULL
```

whereas this:

```
POSITION('Previous subjectid:' in D.comment)=0
```

will be true if and only if `D.comment IS NOT NULL` and `D.comment` does not contain `'Previous subjectid:'`.

So the two conditions are quite different.

Comment: Thanks; I understand the difference now; great answer.

Comment: This question has been answered...no more are needed!

Answer (score 1):

NULL is actually a **no value**.
0 is a pool of bit data.

This is the difference.